# how to solve android telegram with Authorization error. please reinstall the app and log in again with your phone number.?

Tags: telegram

I did secondary development on telegram with android,now Now I have this problem：
When using telegram, a dialog box will pop up and report：Authorization error. please reinstall the app and log in again with your phone number. we apologize for the inconvenience ? I search for long but did not resole the problem, please help me ,thank you very much!